# Ideal of a commutative ring with $30$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring and $|R|=30$. If $I$ is an ideal of R and $|I|=10.$ Prove that $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: Since $R/I$ is a ring with $3$ elements, it can only be $\Bbb F_3$, the field with $3$ elements.

Comment: Why the question says R is commutitve ring

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please note that most people here are put off by questions which are a direct copy of part of an homework assignment, because they show no effort on part of the asker. Could you tell us how you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I could swear this question was asked within the past few days...

Answer (score 1):

If $J$ is an ideal between $I$ and $R$, with $|J|=n$, then we must have $10|n$ and $n|30$.  Where does that leave us?

Answer (score 1):

Although this problem can be solved applying the Lagrange theorem to the additive group of $R$, like paw88789 suggests, it looks like who wrote the exercise had Pedro Tamaroff's solution in mind. Indeed, while it is straightforward to see that $R/I$ must be a field, to be able to take this quotient you must know that $I$ is a two-sided ideal, which is immediate if $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Mmmm ... so to use the facor rings which must be ideal ... it must have commutitve property

Comment: Yes. You could use the argument with quotient rings if the statement included the extra hypothesis that $I$ is two-sided. Without it, you can be sure that you can take the quotient (i.e. consider $R/I$) only if $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Mmmmmm ... now I understand ..the question not stat any thing  to fun ...thank u